# UITableViewCells are deallocated after creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

- I've got a `UITableView` that I am populating with a couple of different subclasses of `UITableViewCell`.
- Right after the cells are created in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`: method, they are deallocated.
- I tossed an `NSLog` statement in each of the custom classes to fire when they are deallocated.
- This is causing all sorts of issues because 1 of the cells is a delegate to a `UICollectionView` thats a subview of the cell.  I'm initializing the cells as shown below so that I can use a xib file to create them.
- Attached is the stack trace pre-dealloc on one of my custom cells

**Nib Registration**

```
[_tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([HVStatusViewCell class]) bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"HVStatusViewCell"];
[_tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([HVActiveGroupCell class]) bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"HVActiveGroupCell"];
```

**Dictionary Holding Section Information**

```
[tableData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"s0-cellcount"];
[tableData setObject:@"HVStatusViewCell"        forKey:@"s0-cellidentifier"];
[tableData setObject:@"Status"                  forKey:@"s0-name"];

[tableData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]   forKey:@"s1-cellcount"];
[tableData setObject:@"HVActiveGroupCell"         forKey:@"s1-cellidentifier"];
[tableData setObject:@"Active Emergency Contacts" forKey:@"s1-name"];
```

**Cell Creation**

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *key             = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"s%li-cellidentifier", (long)indexPath.section];
    NSString *reuseIdentifier = [tableData valueForKey: key];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: reuseIdentifier];

    if (!cell) cell = [[NSClassFromString(reuseIdentifier) alloc] init];

    [cell setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
    return cell;
}
```

**Sample Cell Initialization**

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self){
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil];
        self = [topLevelObjects firstObject];
    }

    return self;
}
```

> Stack trace : (   0   AngelAlert                          0x0004de06 -[HVActiveGroupCell dealloc] + 70    1   UIKit                               0x00bccb94 -[UIView release] + 89   2   CoreFoundation
>   0x026c1bf0 CFRelease + 272    3   CoreFoundation
>   0x026e116e -[**NSArrayM dealloc] + 142    4   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x01ecb692 _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb + 268    5
>
>   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01ecae81 objc_release + 49  6
>
>   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01ecbce7
>   _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 537   7   QuartzCore                          0x02469268
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 108    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0270836e
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 30    9   CoreFoundation                      0x027082bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers
>   + 399     10  CoreFoundation                      0x026e6254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076    11  CoreFoundation                      0x026e59d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467   12  CoreFoundation
>   0x026e57eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   13  GraphicsServices
>   0x03be65ee GSEventRunModal + 192  14  GraphicsServices
>   0x03be642b GSEventRun + 104   15  UIKit
>   0x00b7af9b UIApplicationMain + 1225   16  AngelAlert
>   0x0005e21d main + 141     17  libdyld.dylib
>   0x033d0701 start + 1 )

Comment: If you register a nib, there's no need to check for the cell being nil, because it never will be. Also, you shouldn't be overriding init in your cell's class, registering the nib is all you have to do -- the table view takes care of loading the nib for you. Try deleting that to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: No luck with that.  I went ahead and removed the redundant code though because it has the same functionality without it.

Comment: I see nothing in your code that would cause the cells to be deallocated. Is the table view itself, or the table view controller being deallocated?

Comment: I just double checked that, its not.  The table view stays allocated, which is confusing because I thought rows, for the most part, were deallocated when the tableview that owned them was.

Comment: Are you determining that the cells are being deallocated by a log in their dealloc methods?

Comment: Correct, each of the custom cell class have similar code to:

- (void) dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Dealloc ActiveGroupView");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self];
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51720/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-stephen-donnell)

Comment: I did additional research and logged the cells both before the dealloc event is called and after, and at both points their memory signature is the same.  How could this possibly be the case?

Comment: I don't know. The fact that you can even log them at all after dealloc, must mean that they haven't been deallocated yet (I think).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found out the issue, and its a stupid one.  I was allocating a cell to determine cell height:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"s%li-cellidentifier", (long)indexPath.section];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: [tableData valueForKey: key]];

    return cell.frame.size.height;
}
```

- The cell that was being deallocated was the cell created in this method, not the one in the UITableView
- The connections for delegate and datasource for the UICollectionView were pointing to the NSObject, not the UITableViewCell.  I'm not sure this was causing any issues, but thought it would be worth noting.
- The cell that was displayed in the TableView was persistent, which explains why logging it before and after the dealloc gave me the same memory signature